# If I quit terminal on mac, do I lose all tmux sessions after I re-open terminal?

Tags: tmux

I can't afford to give it a try since I've got a bunch of working tmux sessions running now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not. This is one of the many benefits of using tmux. Simply do `tmux ls` to list all the current sessions open after you re-open your terminal, and then do `tmux a -t <session-name>` to re-attach the session.

---

Although this is very nice, if you shut down or restart your computer, you will in fact lose all of your sessions. To get around this, many people (including myself) use [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect), a plugin that lets you save sessions to disk, and restore them later whenever you want (even after restart).